# Android Bluetooth headset call button not working

Tags: android, bluetooth, call, headset, rfcomm

I want to listen if bluetooth headset button is pressed.
Apparently my headset does not have a media button but only a call button.
Therefore `android.intent.MEDIA_BUTTON` will not work.
I have also tried connecting to the headset via rfcomm in my program to no avail.
Just invalid rfc slot id.

Upon pressing the headset button I do get the following error in the log:

```
Tag:bt-rfcomm Text:PORT_DataInd, p_port:0x697106d0, p_data_co_callback is null
```

So it does get detected. Does anyone have any suggestions?

My device is: **google nexus 7(2012)** and

my headset is: **plantronics ml18**